# What are the technologies which has a prerequest of quantum mechanics

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, technological-development, steampunk, scientific-development

I'm thinking about a world where the planet was wrapped by a force field that experiments which lead to quantum mechanics and special relativity gives the false result. I'm wondering what technology will not appear if people donnot know those theories.

Note: quantum effects are still valid. but people are just not able to know that.

Comment: There would probably be quite different technologies exploiting the properties of the space within this field. Just for example, without special relativity FTL communications would be great for the Internet, especially satellite Internet. But we can’t say what those technologies would be unless you can tell us in detail how the field works.

Comment: Those two theories affect not only technology, but also every living organism: e.g. without quantum theory you won't have chemical reactions, thus life. Unless you specify what are the alternative theories which rule the world, we cannot answer

Comment: "Quantum effects are still valid but people are not able to know that" is a meaningless sentence. For a very simple example: the whole quantum revolution started trying to figure out why hot bodies emit light the way they do. There was no need for expensive instruments, etc. Just heat a chunk of metal and observe the spectrum of the emitted light. (You do know that hot metals become incandescent, right?) The spectrum of the light emitted by hot bodies cannot be explained and calculated using classical mechanics alone; and Max Planck figured out that action *has to* come in discrete quanta.

Comment: P.S. That was in 1900. As for Einsteinian relativity, it falls out of the requirement that all physics be the same in all inertial frames of reference; again, Einstein did not need any fancy equipment to figure it out. (He was quite poor at the time, and did not have access to expensive experimental devices.) As @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica says: for the question to be answerable you need to explain the effects of that mysterious field, because they must be quite subtle to allow life to continue and at the same time cast a veil on reality, so that people cannot figure out